# 'npm init vue@latest' VS 'vue create <projectName>' to generate a new project

Tags: vue.js

I have noticed theese two methods for generating a new vue project:

`npm init vue@latest`

and

`vue create <projectName>`

Both seem to do the job, but very differently, they boundle very different packages.

Even tho you ovbiously modify the project to your liking, **is ther a better start for my project requirements?**.

The project i'm talking about, is going to be a single page web application using typescypt, ESlint and tailwind.

Also I have seen that the two methods do not just install unrelated software from one to the other, for example state management is handled by different libraries, and if I am not wrong Vite is the equivalent to Babel.

**I am just starting with Vue**, and frontend in general (tho i have used Angular), I am more prominently a backend dev, so i am not used to most of the software used here, and I do not really know what they are used for....

Comment: The latter uses Vue CLI and Webpack. The former uses Vite and Rollup. and is currently the recommended one. You may want to learn differences between bundlers. " I am not wrong Vite is the equivalent to Babel" - no, it's an equivalent to Vue CLI, Angular CLI, etc preconfigured bundler setups.

Comment: @EstusFlask Thanks, I'll look for the boundlers difference, but didn't understand which one you mean is the recomended, did you mean the One that uses Vite and Rollup?

Comment: Yes. It's recommended in official docs.

Comment: many old vue projects use `vue create <projectName>` that come with webpack. The current stackblitz.com default vue playground is using webpack + vue 3, and it was using webpack + vue 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To ease finding the solution for others, as commented by Estus Flask, The **oficially recomended** by the vue devs currently is
`npm init vue@latest`.

This will set up a project using **Vite and Rollup**, wich **is the currently recomended stack**.

The other method is a deprecated one. as it gives you the old stack  recomendation, Vue CLI and Webpack, **this other stack is currently not enforced by vue devs**.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Quick start](https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html) documentation, use the `create` command.

```
npm create vue@latest
```

> This command will install and execute create-vue, the official Vue project scaffolding tool.